# Is there any way to link existing inputs to django form?

Tags: python, django, bootstrap-4, django-forms, bootstrap-modal

Working on an app, I initially started developing the UI via QT (PySide2) but I paused it to work on a full "online version" via Django.

The fact is that I'm learning/discovering the framework and how it works step after step.

For all HTML I'm building those on Bootstrap Studio which help me to save **A LOT** of time and of course make things totally easier for me.

My current problem is that I just discovered how not simply inputs/forms work in Django (My own opinion !). My app works with several bootstrap modals in order to Add/Edit "element" which are the kind of instances of my app and which will be write/read/edit in the database.

The problem here is I already created all HTML pages and related bootstrap-modals and I can't find any way on the internet to link my existing bootstrap-modals to Django forms.

As far as I understood Django forms "caricaturaly" works like this: Django generates a form that you have to dynamically integrate into your HTML.

The fact is it doesn't really arrange me because :

- I already have my bootstrap-modals with their inputs looking how I want
- I don't really want a bad looking forms as Django generates
- I have other elements in the form which are not related to a form (progress bar)
- Any other things I have no idea about since I am a beginner in Web!

Therefore, my main question here would be: Is there any simple/accessible way to get the inputs as it would be via QT, by this I mean :

1. Opening the modal
2. Filling Input_1, Input_2, Input_3
3. Any way in Django files to get those inputs and then saves those in DB (one by one)

My apologies if really looks dumb here but I am really new to Django/Web, I know CSS/HTML syntax, I have NO knowledge in JavaScript and I would say that my Python level is Intermediate (enough for all my back-end uses).

Thank you in advance for your help!

Comment: Forms do two things: generate html, and valid form data in requests.  You can create a form and only use it to validate/process the fields in a request that interest you.  You don't need to use the form for html generation (but it will be up to you to ensure the input names in the html match those expected by the form).

Comment: Thank you for your feedback ! The fact is I don't find any documentation for only "validate/process". All tutorials explain the whole process as Django explain themself on their own tutorial related to forms. There's nothing saying "By the way you can use your existing HTML, here how to connect inputs only".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple example of using a form for validation/processing but not html generation.

Assume we have this existing form

```html
<form action="/some-url" method="POST">
    <input id="foo" name="foo" type="text"/>
    <input id="bar" name="bar" type="text"/>
    <input id="baz" name="baz" type="text"/>
</form>
```

you can represent it with this Django form:

```python
class MyForm(forms.Form):
    
    # Field names should match the 'name' attributes in the html inputs
    foo = forms.CharField()
    bar = forms.CharField()
    baz = forms.CharField()
```

And use it in view like this

```python
def my_view(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = MyForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            # Do stuff
            return HttpRedirectResponse('/success')
    # No need to pass the a form to the template, because we aren't
    # using it to generate html.
    return render(request, 'view.html', {})
```

If you want to use a field from the html form separately, without using a Django form at all, access it directly:

```
some_val = request.POST['some_val']
```

(beware of false booleans and disabled fields, which will not be present in request.POST).

Comment: Thank you for these details ! However how should I do then with the following tags since they are used to generate HTML ?

{% csrf_token %}
{{ form.as_p }}

Comment: It's been a while since I used Django, but I'd guess: leave csrf_token in place, assuming you have csrf protection enabled.  For form.as_p, you'll need to replace it with your own hand-crafted  html.

Comment: Thanks, I'll try to test this today and I'll give you a feedback.